# Access violation on C/C++ DLL caller after thread creation

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I'm currently writing a EXT_IO dll for some SDR. However I encounter some problem where the SDR software (i've used HDSDR and SDRSharper) catch an access violation exception after I've created a thread (consumer thread that gets the samples from my frontend). I get those access violation even when the thread i'm creating point to an empty function (one that just return 0). I've tried that because I thought that I my had concurrent access to a buffer.

Sometimes the SDR soft don't catch an exception but simply crash, and I can see in the windows event observer that it crashed because of an access violation.

the thread is in a separated C++ class, that manage all the interaction with my frontend, and is called by an extern C part that is the Ext_IO interface (such as defined [in this document](https://www.i2phd.org/code/Winrad_Extio.pdf) ).

here is the code that create the thread in my C++ class

```
   int startReception()
    {
        try
        {
            PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << "Starting Sample Reception";

            _Consumerthread = _beginthreadex(0, 0, &ArcaleRfTCPServer::receiveThread, this, 0, NULL);
            if (_Consumerthread == NULL) return -1;
            return 0;
        }
        catch (const std::exception& ex)
        {
            PLOGE_(PLOG_ID) << ex.what();
        }
    }

private :

  static unsigned int __stdcall receiveThread(void* p_this)
    {
        ArcaleRfTCPServer* p_ArcaleRfTCPServer = static_cast<ArcaleRfTCPServer*>(p_this);
        p_ArcaleRfTCPServer->recieve(); // Non-static member function!
        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the thread itself

```
void recieve()
    {
        try
        {
        PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << "Starting Reciever Thread";
        _rawData = (char*)calloc(_packetByteSize, sizeof(uint8_t));
        if (_rawData == nullptr)
        {
            throw exception("Memory allocation for reception buffer failed");
        }
        PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << "Memory Allocation was OK";
        while (_active)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int index = 0;
            int bytesleft = _packetByteSize;

            PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << "SuiteRF trying to get lock";
            lock.lock();
            PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << "Locked By SuiteRF";
            while (bytesleft > 0) {
                bytesRead = recieveMessage(_dataSock, &_rawData[index], bytesleft);
                if (bytesRead <= 0) _endthreadex(-1);
                bytesleft -= bytesRead;
                index += bytesRead;
                PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << " read this run = " << bytesRead << "; left = " << bytesleft << "; total read = " << index;
            }
            lock.unlock();
            PLOGV_(PLOG_ID) << "unlocked by SuiteRF";
            _consumer(_rawData, index);
        }
        free(_rawData);
        _rawData = nullptr;
        _endthreadex(0);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, ex.what(), "Reader Thread Error", NULL);
        free(_rawData);
        _rawData = nullptr;
        _endthreadex(-1);
    }
}
```

the consumer is a callback that is defined outside the class is is passed in the class constructor :

```
ArcaleRfTCPServer(int configPort, int DataPort, int timeout, void (*Consumer)(void* raw, int size))
```

and its code is :

```
void __cdecl consumer(void* data, int count)
{
    PLOGD << "Consumer IN";
    int n, j;
    try {
        uint8_t* Raw = (uint8_t*)data;
        SuiteRF->getLock();
        for (n = 0, j = 0; n < count/2; n++, j++) {
            PLOGV << "IQ[" << n << "] = Raw[" << j << "] + Raw[" << j + 1 << "] count is " << count;
            iq[n] = (Raw[j] << 8) + Raw[++j];
        }
        SuiteRF->unlock();
        callback(IQPair, 0, 0, &iq); // we tell the SDR software to get the sample here
        PLOGD << "Consumer OUT";
    }
    catch (const exception& ex)
    {
        PLOGE << ex.what();
    }
}
```

What troubles me is that the access violation error message point towards an exception that would involve DLL whowever, all my code is in try-catch block and none of them catches an exception.

plus SDRSharper tends to tell me that the exception would be when invoking function exported by my DLL that it had invoked without trouble before that thread creation.

Any Idea Why ? I can't see what I'm missing here. I'm pretty sure it's fairly obvious but I can quite catch it.

Thanks for the help

EDIT :

for better understanding the `iq` buffer in consumer is a `static volatile uint16_t` that is allocated half the size of `_rawdata`, hence `J` being incremented twice per loop (combining 2 8 bits into 1 16 bits per sample)

`lock` is a simple `mutex`, but in real it should have no real use because `recieve()` and `consumer()` are synchronous, so no concurrence access to the raw buffer can happen, I implemented that quickly just to be sure.

I don't see an out of bound being the source of those access violation because even if I comment everything in `recieve()` I still get those access violation. plus when not commented, the Access Violation always appear way before `j` or `i` got near the boundary of `iq` or `raw` (can be sure thanks to the PLOGV line just above)

I also tried creating the thread using an `std::thread` instead of the current method, to get rid of the pointers in `recieveThread()` but with the same results

Comment: Unrelated: Consider a `std::vector` instead of `_rawData = (char*)calloc(_packetByteSize, sizeof(uint8_t));` Should be no performance difference onece the optimizer's had a go at it and significantly less leak-prone.

Comment: An access violation is an exception from outside the C++ universe. The OS, CPU, or something lower than the program caught the mistake. It's not catchable with `try`/`catch`. You need to use a signal handler. That said, once you have an access violation, catching it is almost always pointless. Whatever you did to upset the system is still lurking and may be doing damage you haven't seen yet.

Comment: FYI -- `lock.lock(); ... lock.unlock();` -- Whatever `lock` is, it will fail to call `unlock` if `receiveMessage` returns something `<= 0`.  Use RAII and `lock_guard` or similar.

Comment: In `consumer` you should check out the range of `j`. Looks like it's being incremented twice per iteration and likely pushing it out if the valid range for indexing `Raw`.

Comment: technically it's an interrupt, not exception. if it reached that level, it already reached the debugging capabilities of OS. The likely source would be going out of bounds or use of incorrect pointer (which are essentially same thing). Those don't guarantee to generate exceptions, they cause  interrupt on Windows platform

Comment: Totally unrelated: I before E except after C. `recieve` -> `receive`.

Comment: Shouldn't the SEH Exceptions option for visual studio allow me to catch those exception ? I know that catching the access would not solve the problem at all, it would just allow me to see where it is located, so I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer was : PLOG.

As you could see I had 2 instances of plog running. One with the default instance number, outside of my class, the second with instance number `PLOG_ID` (with a `#DEFINE PLOG_ID 42` ) inside of my class.

I removed all references and call to the plog outside my class, keeping only the `PLOGx_(PLOG_ID)` macro that were inside my class and BOOM! no more exceptions.

Or when the tool that is supposed to help is the one causing the problem...

Anyway Thanks guys